# ignition lead replacement

Tags: ford, ignition-coil, falcon

I drive a 1998 Ford Falcon AU with 210,000 km on the clock with original 18-year-old ignition leads. I only drive about 10,000 km per year. The car runs perfectly. Should I replace them? PS. I replace the spark plugs every 60,000km.

Answer (score 1):

Ignition leads don't really wear out like other components do. Sure, they go bad, but it's really not on a schedule or a mileage basis. If you don't have any suspicions that they are causing a misfire, keep them.

If you really want to, you can use a multi-meter and measure the resistance of your ignition leads, make sure it's still within spec.